# DCMTK change logger filename

Tags: dcmtk

I am very confused about the DCMTK > 3.6.0 logging mechanism oflog/log4cplus

I simply need my code to specify the logname for dcmtk to log into. How is that done ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer can be found in DCMTK's "logger howto": https://support.dcmtk.org/redmine/projects/dcmtk/wiki/Howto_LogProgram#Redirecting-log-output-to-a-file

Comment: In the above link the example says "The file is re-created every time the code gets to this point", how do I change that ? I just want to append to an existing file

Comment: Did you already try what the referenced "howto" says:
"If you want to append a file without deleting it, use the following line instead
  log4cplus::SharedAppenderPtr logfile(new log4cplus::FileAppender("example.log", STD_NAMESPACE ios::app));"